# Gutes Beispiel für eine Analogie

Tags: meaning

Ich kann nirgends ein Beispiel für eine glasklare Analogie finden. Gibt es jemanden, der einen oder mehrere Sätze nennen kann, die jemandem aufzeigen, was eine Analogie ist?

Comment: Hallo, ich stelle mir das als schwierig zu lösen vor. Kannst Du uns 1-2 Beispiele von nicht glasklaren Analogien nennen?

Comment: Nein, das ist ja das Problem :-) Beispiele für Metaphern sind leicht zu finden, aber für Analogien finde ich gar kein Beispiel :-(

Comment: Ist deine Frage dann, was der Unterschied zwischen Metapher und Analogie ist? Falls ja, editiere deine Frage doch bitte um :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not specific to German at all. *Analogy* is a metonym for similies, metaphors, etc., largely independent of language. Thus, In a sense, *analogy* might itself be an analogy, if metonyms generally were. *Deutschland hat Merkel gewählt* ist zb eines, wenn eigentlich die Mitglieder des Bundestags Kanzler erwählen; ich jedenfalls sicherlich nicht. Ich wähle nur Fragen zur schließung.

Comment: Meta discussion: [Are question about rhetoric or rhetorical figures on topic?](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1569/35111)

Comment: @SamuelWaeny falls Du noch mitliest: Du kannst deine Frage editieren (grauer Knopf unter der Frage) und anpassen, dann wird sie wieder geöffnet und vermutlich auch beantwortet.

Comment: Sehr schade, dass eine wirklich wunderbare Antwort gelöscht wurde, weil hier offenbar mal wieder jemand so auf die Palme getrieben wurde, dass er keine Lust mehr hat. Für diejenigen, die es nicht sehen können: "glasklare Analogie - *Da haben Sie Ihre Analogie ...* - So klar wie Glas."

Answer (score 2):

Eine Analogie ist eine Entsprechung. Da Entsprechungen immer relativ sind, als Ähnlichkeiten verdeutlichen, ist die Forderung nach "glasklar" schon ein Widerspruch in sich. Definiert man "glasklar" als "äußerst ähnlich", ist immer noch die Frage: Ab wann verdeutlicht die Analogie diese hohe Ähnlichkeit/Entsprechung. Das ist subjektiv.

> Viele Köche verderben den Brei.

wird z.B. verwendet, um zu verdeutlichen, dass es oft schlecht endet, wenn viele gleichberechtigt ohne zentrale Koordinierung an einer Sache herumbasteln.

> [A] braucht [B] wie die Blume das Licht.

verdeutlicht eine extenzielle Abhängigkeit.

Je passender die Entsprechung des Vergleich ist, um so klarer ist die Analogie.